# How can I update a Toga progress bar after each download?

Tags: python, beeware

When the download button is pressed it is supposed to download a set of files from a specified url. After each download I update the progress bar accordingly, but the bar only updates after all the files have been downloaded. The UI is being blocked until all downloads are complete. I am using Beeware's Toga for the UI. I have tried using async and await but the download function is synchronous so it doesn't work.
Below is the code:

```
"""
Downloader
"""
import pathlib, os
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW, LEFT, CENTER, TOP
from downloader.my_libs.downloader import downloader


WHITE = '#ffffff'
PRIMARY_COLOR = '#000000'
SECONDARY_COLOR = '#fbfbfb'
ACCENT_COLOR = '#80ff80'
BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#ffffff'


class Downloader(toga.App):
    def __init__(self, formal_name=None, app_id=None, app_name=None, id=None, icon=None, author=None, version=None, home_page=None, description=None, startup=None, windows=None, on_exit=None, factory=None):
        super().__init__(formal_name, app_id, app_name, id, icon, author, version, home_page, description, startup, windows, on_exit, factory)
        self.resource_folder = pathlib.Path(__file__).joinpath('../resources').resolve()
        self.url_filename = self.resource_folder.joinpath('url.txt')
        self.output_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).joinpath('../../../../files').resolve()
        self.downloader = Downloader(url='', output_path=self.output_path)
        self.number_of_items_downloaded = 0
        self.number_of_items_to_download = 0

    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(background_color=BACKGROUND_COLOR))
        box = toga.Box(style=Pack(background_color=BACKGROUND_COLOR))
        url_box = toga.Box()

        title_label = toga.Label(text='Downloader', style=Pack(text_align=CENTER, font_size=20, flex=1, background_color=BACKGROUND_COLOR, color=PRIMARY_COLOR))
        self.url_input = toga.TextInput(style=Pack(flex=4, font_size=12, background_color=SECONDARY_COLOR, color=PRIMARY_COLOR))
        self.download_button = toga.Button('Download', on_press=self.on_download, style=Pack(flex=1, font_size=12, padding_top=5, background_color=ACCENT_COLOR, color=PRIMARY_COLOR))
        self.info_box = toga.MultilineTextInput(readonly=True, style=Pack(flex=1, padding_top=10, font_size=12, background_color=SECONDARY_COLOR, color=PRIMARY_COLOR))
        self.progress_bar = toga.ProgressBar(max=100, value=0, style=Pack(padding_top=10, background_color=SECONDARY_COLOR, color=ACCENT_COLOR))

        box.add(title_label)
        url_box.add(self.url_input)
        box.add(url_box)
        box.add(self.download_button)
        box.add(self.info_box)
        box.add(self.progress_bar)
        main_box.add(box)

        box.style.update(direction=COLUMN, padding=50, flex=1)
        url_box.style.update(direction=ROW, flex=1, padding_top=5)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    def on_download(self, widget):
        self.progress_bar.start()
        self.download_files()
        self.progress_bar.stop()
    
    def download_files(self):
        self.number_of_items_to_download = len(self.downloader.urls)

        for url in self.downloader.urls:
            try:
                self.download_file(url)
                self.update_progress()
            except Exception as exception:
                print('Could not download from:', url)
                print(exception, '\n\n')
                self.info_box.value = self.info_box.value + f'\nCould not download from: {url}' + f'exception\n\n'

    def update_progress(self):
        self.progress_bar.value = (self.number_of_items_downloaded / self.number_of_items_to_download) * 100

    def download_file(self, url):
        title, filepath = self.downloader.download(url)
        self.info_box.value = self.info_box.value + f'Downloaded {title} \nTo {filepath}\n\n'
        self.number_of_items_downloaded += 1


def main():
    return Downloader()
```

Comment: Have you tried threading? Something like `download_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.download_files)`, and then starting and joining the thread? You can apparently access the required functions via `self.main_window.info.invoke(self.update_progress)` but I have not tested this.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I am not well versed in threading, would I join the thread at the end of on_download()? Also, would I need to add the thread to the class in_it like self.download_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.download_files)

Comment: You join the thread at the point where you expect it to be finished; so, you'd likely join it immediately after starting it. That's usually the case.

Comment: I added the download thread to init, started it in on_download then joined it right after progress_bar.stop() in the same method, but the program just hangs after clicking download and is unresponsive.

Comment: You'll just have to play around with it, get familiar with threading, and get familiar with how in general to not block UIs. There's probably lots of info and tutorials online for how to, in any UI framework and any language, make sure that you aren't blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Also, I get this error when using self.main_window.info.invoke(self.update_progress) ->"'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'info'". I checked the docs there is no info attribute for main window or window for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main principles to remember in most UI frameworks are:

- Don't block the main thread for more than a small fraction of a second.
- Don't touch UI objects on any thread *except* the main one.

Here's a solution that follows both of those rules. I haven't tested it, but it should be pretty close:

```py
    def on_download(self, widget):
        # As of Toga 0.4, self.loop is pre-set by Toga itself, 
        # so the next line should be removed.
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        threading.Thread(target=self.download_files).start()
    
    def download_files(self):
        self.number_of_items_to_download = len(self.downloader.urls)

        for url in self.downloader.urls:
            try:
                self.download_file(url)
            except Exception as exception:
                print('Could not download from:', url)
                print(exception, '\n\n')
                # TODO: use call_soon_threadsafe to update the UI
                # self.info_box.value = self.info_box.value + f'\nCould not download from: {url}' + f'exception\n\n'

    def update_progress(self, title, filepath):
        self.info_box.value = self.info_box.value + f'Downloaded {title} \nTo {filepath}\n\n'
        self.progress_bar.value = (self.number_of_items_downloaded / self.number_of_items_to_download) * 100

    def download_file(self, url):
        title, filepath = self.downloader.download(url)
        self.number_of_items_downloaded += 1
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.update_progress, title, filepath)
```

There's no need to `join` the thread. If you want to update the UI when the download is complete, just do that with another call to `call_soon_threadsafe`.

Even better, you could use a higher-level API like `run_in_executor`:

```py
    # Must add `async`!
    async def on_download(self, widget):  
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.number_of_items_to_download = len(self.downloader.urls)

        for url in self.downloader.urls:
            try:
                title, filepath = await loop.run_in_executor(
                    None, self.downloader.download, url 
                )
                self.info_box.value = self.info_box.value + f'Downloaded {title} \nTo {filepath}\n\n'
                self.number_of_items_downloaded += 1
                self.progress_bar.value = (self.number_of_items_downloaded / self.number_of_items_to_download) * 100
            except Exception as exception:
                print('Could not download from:', url)
                print(exception, '\n\n')
                self.info_box.value = self.info_box.value + f'\nCould not download from: {url}' + f'exception\n\n'
```

Comment: Thanks mhsmith, both of these methods worked and I went with the second way of using run_in_executor. I did change a couple things. One, I set the loop as a class var in init. This was required as the event loop did not properly set using the above code (second option only). Two, I used the download_file method (from your first option) in the run_in_executor instead of calling download from the downloader directly.

Comment: That should be fine, as long as download_file doesn't access any UI objects on the background thread.